# unity3D, enemy following issue

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make enemies follow my player when the player enters the radius area of an enemy, but make the enemy stop following when my bullet hits `object` or enters `radiusArea`.

See my gif for more detail:

**[Gif](http://i.imgur.com/ngVIYPs.gif?1)**

script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FlyEnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float playerRange;
    public LayerMask playerLayer;
    public bool playerInRange;

    PlayerController thePlayer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        flip();
        playerInRange = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, playerRange, playerLayer);
        if (playerInRange)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, thePlayer.transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            //Debug.Log(transform.position.y);

        }
        //Debug.Log(playerInRange);
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, playerRange);
    }

    void flip()
    {
        if (thePlayer.transform.position.x < transform.position.x)
        {

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2377247f, 0.2377247f, 0.2377247f);
        }
        else
        {

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-0.2377247f, 0.2377247f, 0.2377247f);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me :(

Comment: your gif is not working, sad!

Comment: Just like joe said, you image link is not working. I fixed it. Make sure to test your image link time.

Answer (score 1):

`Physics2D.OverlapCircle` detects only the collider with the lowest z value (if multiple are in range). So you either need to change the z values so the player has the lowest or you need to work with `Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll` and check the list to find the player. Or you could change your layers so only the player itself is on that specific layer you feed into the overlap test.

Comment: Your gif actually looks like the enemy stops following the player for some other reason. In the moment it stops, nothing other happens than that the player moves. Does the enemy get stuck on something? Did you check if `playerInRange` is still true? (Put a Debug.Log for example.)